# Saving document to library then automatically sorted to folder

Tags: save, dip

Is there anyway to save a document to a library root location with its Document information panel already filled out and then have the document save to the folder path designated by the criteria in the Document Information Panel?

Answer (score 0):

You can set default values for library items, or use some sort of workflow to populate the values.

You can use workflow or content organizer functions to move items to specified locations based on certain data.

With a bit more info I could probably provide a more detailed answer on how to.accomplish that.